# Redundant Training Samples

Tags: classification, svm

I am building a prediction model based on SVM model with RBF kernel. The training samples represent features obtained from genome regions (called binding sites) that are targeted (regulated) by proteins. The model will learn to distinguish between regions targeted by proteins and regions that are not. (I created positive and negative data).

My question is that the positive data contains redundant training samples (i.e. identical binding sites at different locations of the genome) so, shall I keep the redundant training samples (to make the model learn more about a specific pattern of targeted region) or I should keep only the unique training samples?

For example: I have in the training samples 10,000 samples represent 10,000 different target regions (binding sites) of proteins. If I take the unique, it will be around 7,000 samples. (Because the binding sites might be identical in different locations)

Comment: What will you use the model for? The training data should closely match the intended use. If the reason for the redundant training samples is that they are more common, and they will also be more common when you use the model to make predictions, then you should keep them.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisTaylor. The intended use is to learn the model with the patterns of the target sequences of proteins, so, we train it with samples of real target sequences (positives) and incorrect sequences (negatives0. So, some target sequences are more common, and we expect them to be more common when we use the model to make predictions

Comment: In that case I would keep the 'redundant' sequences.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, please make that an answer.

Comment: @BenReiniger done

Answer (score 1):

What will you use the model for? The training data should closely match the intended use. If the reason for the redundant training samples is that they are more common, and they will also be more common when you use the model to make predictions, then you should keep them.